# Android build for QT C++ application that has python call

Tags: python, c++, qt

I have an QT C++ application that calls a python script. My application is working good when I creates the Executable in Ubuntu platform. However, i could not create the Andriod build for the application and it creates the below Error.

Environment: QT5.15.2 and Ubuntu20.04.

I have added the below lines in the Project file and I have added #include <python.h> in the CPP file where it calls the Python script.

```
INCLUDEPATH = /usr/include/python3.8
LIBS += -lpython3.8
```

Error

> /usr/include/python3.8/pyconfig.h:15: error:
> 'arm-linux-gnueabi/python3.8/pyconfig.h' file not found In file
> included from
> /home/vinoth/qgroundcontrol_UI/src/QmlControls/AWSOperations.cpp:6: In
> file included from /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h:8:
> /usr/include/python3.8/pyconfig.h:15:12: fatal error:
> 'arm-linux-gnueabi/python3.8/pyconfig.h' file not found include
> <arm-linux-gnueabi/python3.8/pyconfig.h>

Please suggest how to build android build in this scenario

Comment: Embedding Python on Android is not a feature what the main stream supports and is not a trivial work. I recommend to use an existing tool, such as Kivy(Python-for-android), BeeWare, PyBridge, etc. See [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Android). (It's old and somewhat incorrect and but a good start.)